# Can one use ethereum as a client over Tor?

Tags: synchronization, anonymity, tor, node-discovery

Does ethereum work when there is only TCP available?

Can one use ethereum as a client over Tor?

It does not work for me. Using Whonix. So running the traffic over Tor is not an issue. Blockchain download never starts.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it possible to run a client behind an onion address?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1632/87)

Comment: I don't think it's the same. The previous question is asking about connecting to Tor's hidden services (which could be hosting a peer node), whereas this question is just asking about routing Ethereum traffic over Tor. Possibly the same general answer, but the specifics are different.

Comment: @Richard Horrocks , Could you please say what do you mean by _**"routing Ethereum traffic"**_ ? Do we have **routing** process on the Ethereum network? AFAIK, on Ethereum, similar to Bitcoin network, data is only being broadcast.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @sas - I think I just meant "you can't send network traffic being broadcast by Ethereum clients over Tor" (for the reason in my answer below). I think the actual routing it done lower down the protocol stack by the regular routing protocols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ethereum [requires UDP port 30301 for node discovery](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/809/which-tcp-and-udp-ports-are-required-to-run-an-ethereum-client), and Tor only supports TCP-based transport. It's likely that your blockchain sync hasn't started because your client can't find any peers.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1855