# How can I find ETC nodes (to pass their enode URI to --reserved-peers) because the classic chain no longer syncs through tor?

Tags: synchronization, ethereum-classic, peers, tor

I was syncing the ETC chain on parity through tor. Everything worked fine. I got to block 3,000,001. Everything stopped, I realized there was a hardfork. I updated the software (ETH worked fine), but I never could find any peers or sync anymore after that on the ETC chain. I tried version 1.4.10, and 1.5 with fresh installs on linux. Nothing seems to work anymore for parity through tor for classic.

According to these github posts https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/4343 
it seems that the parity install comes with some addresses of known nodes, but that list is outdated or those nodes are no longer working, and I can't find new ones because peer discovery is done through UDP and tor only runs through TCP. Is this an accurate understanding? If so what can I do to find out about new nodes to add manually by passing their enode URI to --reserved-peers as explained in that github post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...and I can't find new ones because peer discovery is done through
>   UDP and tor only runs through TCP. Is this an accurate understanding?

[Yes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1912/52).

As per the issue thread you linked to, you could attempt to add peers (using `--reserved-peers`) from the hard-coded bootnodes list in the ETC (go-ethereum, not Parity) codebase, located in [`bootnodes.go`](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/bootnodes.go#L26).

The list, as of late January 2017, is as follows:

```
enode://08c7ee6a4f861ff0664a49532bcc86de1363acd608999d1b76609bb9bc278649906f069057630fd9493924a368b5d1dc9b8f8bf13ac26df72512f6d1fabd8c95@45.32.7.81:30303
enode://e809c4a2fec7daed400e5e28564e23693b23b2cc5a019b612505631bbe7b9ccf709c1796d2a3d29ef2b045f210caf51e3c4f5b6d3587d43ad5d6397526fa6179@174.112.32.157:30303
enode://687be94c3a7beaa3d2fde82fa5046cdeb3e8198354e05b29d6e0d4e276713e3707ac10f784a7904938b06b46c764875c241b0337dd853385a4d8bfcbf8190647@95.183.51.229:30303
enode://6e538e7c1280f0a31ff08b382db5302480f775480b8e68f8febca0ceff81e4b19153c6f8bf60313b93bef2cc34d34e1df41317de0ce613a201d1660a788a03e2@52.206.67.235:30303
enode://ca5ae4eca09ba6787e29cf6d86f7634d07aae6b9e6317a59aff675851c0bf445068173208cf8ef7f5cd783d8e29b85b2fa3fa358124cf0546823149724f9bde1@138.68.1.16:30303
enode://217ebe27e89bf4fec8ce06509323ff095b1014378deb75ab2e5f6759a4e8750a3bd8254b8c6833136e4d5e58230d65ee8ab34a5db5abf0640408c4288af3c8a7@188.138.1.237:30303
enode://fa20444ef991596ce99b81652ac4e61de1eddc4ff21d3cd42762abd7ed47e7cf044d3c9ccddaf6035d39725e4eb372806787829ccb9a08ec7cb71883cb8c3abd@50.149.116.182:30303
enode://4bd6a4df3612c718333eb5ea7f817923a8cdf1bed89cee70d1710b45a0b6b77b2819846440555e451a9b602ad2efa2d2facd4620650249d8468008946887820a@71.178.232.20:30304
enode://921cf8e4c345fe8db913c53964f9cadc667644e7f20195a0b7d877bd689a5934e146ff2c2259f1bae6817b6585153a007ceb67d260b720fa3e6fc4350df25c7f@51.255.49.170:30303
enode://ffea3b01c000cdd89e1e9229fea3e80e95b646f9b2aa55071fc865e2f19543c9b06045cc2e69453e6b78100a119e66be1b5ad50b36f2ffd27293caa28efdd1b2@128.199.93.177:3030
enode://ee3da491ce6a155eb132708eb0e8d04b0637926ec0ae1b79e63fc97cb9fc3818f49250a0ae0d7f79ed62b66ec677f408c4e01741504dc7a051e274f1e803d454@91.121.65.179:40404
enode://48e063a6cf5f335b1ef2ed98126bf522cf254396f850c7d442fe2edbbc23398787e14cd4de7968a00175a82762de9cbe9e1407d8ccbcaeca5004d65f8398d759@159.203.255.59:30303
enode://42d8f29d1db5f4b2947cd5c3d76c6d0d3697e6b9b3430c3d41e46b4bb77655433aeedc25d4b4ea9d8214b6a43008ba67199374a9b53633301bca0cd20c6928ab@104.155.176.151:30303
```

Comment: How do I actually type that in the terminal though? Like, parity -j --chain=classic --reserved-peers (then do I copy and paste them and separate them with commas?)

Comment: I've tidied up the list. Copy and paste it into a file, then pass the file as the argument to the `--reserved-peers` flag. :)