# How do I pass enode URI's to --reserved-peers?

Tags: synchronization, parity, ethereum-classic, peers, tor

So I know I have to type in terminal:

> parity -j --reserved-peers

But I do not know what to type after --reserved-peers, The actual peers I want to add are listed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11852/how-can-i-find-etc-nodes-to-pass-their-enode-uri-to-reserved-peers-because-t). But I do not know if I am supposed to type them into the terminal after --reserved-peers with some kind of notation, like commas separating them, or if I am supposed to put them in a file somehow and type the file name.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity), you pass a file containing the list as the argument to the `--reserved-peers` flag:

```
  --reserved-peers FILE          Provide a file containing enodes, one per line.
                                 These nodes will always have a reserved slot on top
                                 of the normal maximum peers. (default: None)
```