# How can I configure Ethereum to run over Tor or I2P

Tags: privacy

If Tor or I2P support is not yet practical, is there a guide of best practices to help protect IP and other metadata?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If Tor or I2P support is not yet practical...

Running over Tor currently won't work due to Ethereum's requirement of [UDP port 30301](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/809/which-tcp-and-udp-ports-are-required-to-run-an-ethereum-client), and the fact that Tor only supports TCP.

I2P is actually more interesting. There are two protocols implemented on I2P: [NTCP](https://geti2p.net/en/docs/transport/ntcp) (NIO-TCP), and [SSU](https://geti2p.net/en/docs/transport/ssu) (Secure Semireliable UDP). It'd be an interesting project to see if Ethereum could be made to work using these.

With regards to what protection *is* present, the main thing to note would be that all communication between nodes is via the [ÐΞVp2p Wire Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol) (an encrypted and authenticated transport protocol), as discussed in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4138/are-communications-encrypted/4142#4142) previous thread.